# Awareness of unconditional positive regard

Tags: cognitive-psychology, clinical-psychology, positive-psychology, person-centered-therapy

When [Unconditional Positive Regard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconditional_positive_regard) is in use through several therapy sessions and a client asks about this technique. What explanation should be given?

Comment: To those that voted to close: What is unclear about this question? It is perfectly intelligible, as the answer illustrates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unconditional Positive Regard is one of the [core conditions](http://counsellingtutor.com/counselling-approaches/person-centred-approach-to-counselling/carl-rogers-core-conditions/) in Person Centered Counselling and so is congruence.

In order for you to provide Unconditional  Positive Regard (UPR), you need to be congruent and in order for you to be congruent you need to be genuine in your responses.  Therefore, you should only provide the truth to any question asked.

You need to tell them what UPR is and that in order for UPR to exist you will be non-judgemental and you would provide a safe and warm environment for them to explore what is troubling them in the here and now.